# intelliji or android studio - short cut to create method test case

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, junit, android-studio

Is there a short cut to create a test method quickly in IntelliJ?  What I want to happen is if I already have a test class called TestClass, then in my Class file if I create a new method I could right click on the new method and click something like 'create test' on the method itself.  There is an option available for the class but I can't see it for the method level.  Take a look at this photo and you'll see that the option is available for the class(by pressing alt + enter), but I'd like it available for the method also.

[image: on the class level]

**UPDATE**: It seems the option might be in IntelliJ but I cannot find this in Android Studio 1.1.  When I hit alt+enter on a method in android studio (where the hosting class already has a test case) I get this menu:

[image]

and here is the funny thing in android studio, if I go into the test case class itself then I see an option to create test method within that class. It's just not showing up in the concrete class I need to be tested:

[image]

Comment: What IntelliJ version are you using? When I hit ALT+ENTER on method name I get option _Generate missed test methods_. When I select it, it shows a list of all methods which do not have unit tests, with only the one you hit ALT+ENTER on selected by default. After you hit ENTER a test method is then created in the existing JUnit test class for it. I'm using latest IntelliJ IDEA btw.

Comment: Can you define "latest", please. 14.0.3 ?

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes 14.0.3 (latest stable release)

Comment: Method has to be public to have this option for test generation. I had the same problem for protected methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this (tested in IntelliJ 14.0.3):

- Navigate to the method you wish to create a unit test for
- Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Select *Generate Missed Test Methods*

After that dialog will be shown, containing all methods in a given class with only the one you invoked the *Generate Missed Test Methods* action on selected by default. After you hit OK in the dialog a new test method for selected methods will be added to the existing unit test class.

Here is also a screenshot of the dialog:

[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't found the corresponding action in the keymap settings, so this probably can't be bound directly to some custom keyboard shortcut and it's only accessible via the ALT-ENTER menu.

Comment: i cant find this option in android studio. I thought android studio is a subset of Intelliji.

Comment: @j2emanue, yes, AS is based on Idea. When press `Alt + Enter`, select `Create test`.

Answer (score 50):

Android Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or Navigate->Test.

Comment: Cmd + Shift + T on mac

Answer (score 15):

For MacOS, it is:

<kbd>Command (or Cmd) ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. I had to actually click the item in the menu (the keyboard shortcut opened something else)

[image]

Comment: @Honghe.Wu answered the same: Ctrl+Shift+T (Cmd + Shift + T) or Navigate->Test.

Comment: As per my comment above, the keyboard shortcut didn't work (not sure why - this was a very long time ago!)

Comment: Well, sometimes it happens. For instance, Ctrl + Shift + M doesn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665905/android-studio-extract-method-shortcut-ctrlaltm-not-working/51493800.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only create a method, the shortcut is:

1. <kbd>Command (or Cmd) ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Select Test function
3. Input the perfect name for your test

[image]