# Android Studio "extract method" shortcut Ctrl+Alt+M not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-2.3, extract-method

The android studio shortcut for extract function is not working for me. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> nothing is happening and when I tried to remap it to the same shortcut, I noticed that android studio doesn't seem to recognize the shortcut at all. So I tested my keyboard and everything should be working. I even reinstalled AS no dice.

Answer (score 33):

I found out that Nvidia Geforce Experience was capturing `Ctrl + Alt + M` shortcuts from android studio, even though I wasn't running any game, and didn't run any game recently. 
To disable this annoyance go to Nvidia Geforce Experience settings and disable in-game overlay.
If it does't work check other program that you installed recently for some kind of overlay, hotkey or keyboard shortcut capturing.

Comment: If you want to search this program, see https://windows10skill.com/solved-geforce-experience-wont-open-windows-10/. For instance, open "Uninstall a program" in Control Panel interface, then look for. If "NVidia" doesn't exist, then it is not your case.

Comment: That's the second time Nvidia is getting in the way of Android Studio for me. Thanks! This was driving me crazy and I would have never considered another software.

Comment: Did anyone find a way to fix the NVIDIA issue without disabling the In-game Overlay?

Comment: I found it how to fix this NVIDIA GeForce Experience problem without disabling the in-game overlay, first you need to open the in-game overlay settings (Alt + Z): 
1. Open GeForce Experience > Go To Settings > Find "IN-GAME OVERLAY" then click Settings next to it 
2. Keyboard Shortcuts > Toggle Microphone On/Off > remove it.

Comment: Gosh Nvidia! Thanks!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would one find out which program is capturing the keyboard events?

Comment: Just to add a bit to @Machado's suggestion: in order to remove a keyboard shortcut, you gotta try to bind it to "Delete"

Answer (score 5):

I think some program captures this hotkey. See https://superuser.com/questions/1282799/what-is-preventing-ctrl-alt-m-from-reaching-intellij-on-windows-10, https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows. After an hour of finding hotleys with these programs I still don't know which one is capturing.

I tried some programs to show a list of Windows hotkeys. I tried to assign new hotkeys in AS and other applications (Libre Office). They don't catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, while catch other.

Currently I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, I added it to shortcuts (see below). You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then press <kbd>8</kbd>. Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

UPDATE

On self-isolation I carried a PC home. Plugged *another keyboard*, now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> works. Even if I assign this combination to other applications like Libre Office.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Mac users: `Command` + `Option` + `M`

Comment: That was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut Ctrl+Alt+M is assigned to other function in Android Studio, search it and change shoorcut. It will works

Comment: it as ctrl+alt+m as standard, and i cant even type it to assign it. Seems to be a hardware issue

Comment: Or you can change standard shortcut, i have the same issue.

Comment: yeah thats what i did

Answer (score 0):

Besides what is already suggested as a culprit (Nvidia Geforce Experience in-game overlay), I found out another one.

When you have Macrium Reflect installed on your machine, the same shortcut will open a blank window (which is initially hidden in bakground, by the way, so the connection was not so evident).
I'm not sure what's the purpose of this windows, but right there you have the chance to enable/disable that shortcut, as in following picture:

[image]